# Does the Masuda method work with different species of Pokemon, besides Ditto?

Tags: pokemon-series

I'm currently trying to breed to get a shiny Espurr for my friend, but I'm using an Espurr that i caught myself, and an Eevee from Japan. Will the Masuda method still work with two totally different Pokemon, besides Ditto? I'm only at 93 eggs so far, but I just want to be sure my work isn't in vain. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The Masuda method for breeding shiny Pokémon will work with any combination of pokémon, provided the two are from different regions (which in your specific case they are).

Ditto are a popular choice for the "other region" Pokémon because they can breed with anything (that can breed) without having to worry about egg groups.

Answer (score -3):

Technicly, you can't get shiny pokemon(or in this case espurr while breeding with ditto, even if the ditto is french or japenese or even spanish(yes i did get one).